# How to broadcast a transaction anonymously

Tags: transactions, bitcoind, privacy

Is it possible to broadcast a transaction to the network without revealing my personal IP address? My first guess is to connect bitcoind over Tor with proxy=127.0.0.1:9050. Is it the good way to do it or do I have other options?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can one remain relatively anonymous while using Bitcoin?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-can-one-remain-relatively-anonymous-while-using-bitcoin)

Comment: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/52/659 has some useful information about anonymity too.

Comment: If I want to connect over Tor the client will not be able to discover new peers by itself. Should I use a list of peers with .onion addresses. I saw some info here. https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes Can anyone who use bitcoind over Tor guide me on how to do it right?

Comment: Someone needs to set up a web server that accepts bitcoin transactions for submission. Then you could just use Tor to submit the transaction by HTTP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution I found to broadcast transaction on the bitcoin network without revealing your IP: connect bitcoind over the Tor network. Here is my guide.

Edit your torrc file to add .onion bitcoin nodes:

```
mapaddress 192.0.2.2 ijzt2eeizty3p5xe.onion
mapaddress 192.0.2.3 j43z65b6r2usg3vk.onion
mapaddress 192.0.2.4 pvuif6nonbhj3o3r.onion
```

Start Tor

Edit .bitcoin/bitcoin.conf to connect bitcoind over the Tor network. Add:

```
proxy=127.0.0.1:9050
connect=192.0.2.2
connect=192.0.2.3
connect=192.0.2.4
```

When Tor is started (green onion) you can launch bitcoind.

More infos 
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Fallback_Nodes 
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=50547.0;all

Comment: But and what about this? https://www.cryptocoinsnews.com/bitcoin-tor-may-good-idea/