# How can one remain relatively anonymous while using Ripple?

Tags: ripple, privacy

Inspired by [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/ripplers/comments/1c51u2/anonymous_ripple/) and [that](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/439/how-can-one-remain-relatively-anonymous-while-using-bitcoin).

What can an individual that uses Ripple do in order to remain as anonymous as possible? How do Ripple's "anonymity profile" compare to Bitcoin?

One specific difference is that Ripple accounts need XRP to be opened, and that XRP has to come from somewhere, while Bitcoin accounts are free to create.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Current client doesn't expose it yet, but each account is really an Account Family of un-linkable addresses which can be single use.

https://ripple.com/wiki/Account_Family

Comment: Damn, those Ripple devs thought of everything!

Comment: They incorporated all the lessons of bitcoin and more

Comment: Wouldn't the trust network give away identities though?

Comment: It's easy to be anonymous in the crowd trusting a major gateway, real use of human-to-human trust network will have to wait for some serious project to create an easy to understand UI and some actual compelling use for it, which I believe there are plenty of but this stuff is still way ahead of even almost most ripple nerds :-)