# Can one receiving address from my Wallet be linked to another from the same Wallet?

Tags: address, electrum, receiving

I have created a wallet using Electrum. Electrum creates 20 receiving addresses. My question is can these be linked or traced back to each other?

I want to understand if I have create another wallet if I want more receiving addresses apart from 20.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/7447/is-it-possible-to-figure-out-whether-two-addresses-are-in-the-same-wallet

Comment: Related: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-anonymous-are-bitcoin-transactions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but as far as I know this is not (easily?) possible. The addresses used for sending/receiving payments are created using your initial private key (THe 20 word long seed) in a **deterministic** way. When creating a new wallet with this pivate key, the same addresses are generated.

It is not possible to guess your private key having one or more of your addresses. I think it's also not possible to guess which private key has generated the addresses.

You should use an address only for one transaction.