# Are Bitcoins anonymous or tracable? Any changes from "How anonymous are Bitcoin transactions?"?

Tags: privacy

After the hacking and closing of Mt Gox there has naturally been some talk if there is a way to recover the lost coins.  One "expert" commented that this would be a great test of the claim that BitCoins could be easily traced and thus supirior to other currencies in cases like this...

*I* (on the other hand) was under the impression that BitCoins were anonymous - or at least semi-anonymous... with som precautions.

Now I've read the "How anonymous are Bitcoin transactions?" on this site, and things are a bit clearer to me.  But this seems to (partly) contradict the claim that BitCoins are especially tracable.

So what is correct?  Has there been any major changes since the "How anonymous are Bitcoin transactions?" was written?

[How anonymous are Bitcoin transactions?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-anonymous-are-bitcoin-transactions)

Comment: The situation hasn't changed from when that question was answered. The protocol of Bitcoin still works the same.

Comment: @Luca Matteis: But can the willingness and/or ability (eg. through access to servers at "chockepoints", logs required by law or authorities access) have changed?  Like for example some unholly alliance between the FBI, NSA and IRS...

Comment: `One "expert" commented that this would be a great test of the claim that BitCoins could be easily traced` Mt. Gox asks for a name and address when you sign up. It shouldn't be surprising if they know your name and address. That said, I don't think users are likely to get Bitcoins back unless they hire a lawyer in Japan.

Comment: If you just want to get an update on another question, the best way is probably to add a comment on it or to offer a bounty there.