# How do I pay Utility Bills anonymously with Bitcoin?

Tags: privacy, payment

I can get my salary with Bitcoin: https://bitwage.com/
I can get loans with Bitcoin: https://bitbond.com/
Can I pay my utility bills with Bitcoin? If the naming pattern follows, there's a https://bitutility.com out there for me. I just haven't found it, yet.

So far, I've found bitwala.com, but I can't tell if they require a name on the payment.

Say, ***hypothetically*** that a Bitcoin user had reason to ensure his name goes with his physical address on as few documents as possible.

Assuming that a Bitcoin user [has a pseudonymous account](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/52/how-anonymous-are-bitcoin-transactions?rq=1), how can that user, in general terms, use Bitcoin to pay utility bills with Bitcoin anonymously?

Alternatives:

1. Anonymous PayPal
2. One of those $200 prepaid VISA debit cards
3. Cash at the Utility's office

I imagine that the issues are mostly logistics, as the companies do not care who pays a bill as long as it's paid, right?

Comment: A company does not care whose wallet the money ultimately came from as long as they know that YOU paid YOUR bill, but if one customer pays double and ten pay nothing (assuming for simplicity that they all had the same charge on their accounts), then how would they choose which of the non-payers to give the grace to? The way they do things is to keep track for each customer the exact difference between what your bills have been and what you've paid.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in canada, Bylls.com is exactly what you are looking for. It is for Canadians only though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like bitwala.com provides this service, [although I'm not sure whether we may use it to pay bills in the US](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=944782.msg16528357#msg16528357).

https://www.billpayforcoins.com/ and https://coinsfer.com/ look worth trying for this, too, but I'm not sure yet what level of privacy they allow, if any.

If they allow privacy, they could be used, perhaps, to anonymously pay someone else's bills as a surprise.